# Android Style Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light set as default and is not a Theme

Tags: android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

i have a project in Android Studio where my manifest Have this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Glin"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivityJava"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".location.LocationActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Location" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.RepairTagActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.UHFMainActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Main"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my thEmes:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Glin" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/low_blue</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/gray</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/ligth_blue</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/middle_blue</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/petroleum</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.Glinvergy.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Glin.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.Glin.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ligth_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/ligth_blue</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/ligth_blue</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>

        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

and my styles have this style as one of them:

```
<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

for some strange reason, when i quit this last style, my login_fragment appears without toolbar, so is fine by me, but when i put it, my login fragment appears with a toolbar and everything inside my app appears with 2 toolbars, the problems that other activity inside my app require this style. need some help with that

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache and restart, it's not successfully , clean your project and rebuild project.